# A map of vectors using derived class

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{
protected:
   int x;
public:
   Base();
   ~Base();
   virtual void displayx(){
     cout << x << endl;
   }
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
   Derived();
   ~Derived();
   void displayx(){
     cout << x << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
Base * tanuki;

tanuki = new Derived;

//Unsure about these final lines of code.
std::map< string, vector<Base*>> myMap;

myMap.insert(make_pair("raccoon",vector<....*>()));
}
```

I want to be able to store the new instances of Derived within myMap.
Then call the displayx() function with the specified identifier string from map.
I've tried multiple things but I believe I've hit a wall.

How am I supposed to insert the derived class 'Derived' of base class 'Base' into my map of vectors?

Comment: I think you need to make it clear what do you want to achieve. e.g. Derived from what?

Comment: You want a *vector* of Base*'s for each string in the map?

Comment: @kfsone I was still trying to figure things out for that line of code. Should I have just left it as vector<Base> for what I wanted to achieve?

Comment: No, don't use `vector<Base>` if you plan to store derived objects there. I was just curious if you actually want more than one `Base*` for every `string` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
std::map< string, vector<Base*>> myMap;
```

What you have is a mapping from a string to a vector of Base* pointers. So you'll need to look-up the given vector that maps to "racoon" and then push_back to it.

```
auto& racoon = myMap["racoon"];  // reference to the vector
racoon.push_back(tanuki);
```

which you could also write as

```
myMap["racoon"].push_back(tanuki);
```

Another possibility

```
auto it = myMap.find("racoon");
if (it == myMap.end())
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, std::vector<Base*>>("racoon", {tanuki}));
else
    it->second.push_back(tanuki);
```

(see http://ideone.com/Odgl2y)

--- EDIT ---

You wanted to call displayx, here is how you would call displayx on all the elements of the vector for racoon:

```
auto it = myMap.find("racoon");
if (it == myMap.end()) {
    // it->first is the key, it->second is the value, i.e the vector
    for (Base* b : it->second) {
        b->displayx();
    }
}
```

--- EDIT 2 ---

In C++98, to *insert* a new element into the map, you would do this:

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, std::vector<Base*>>("racoon", std::vector<Base*>()));
```

or if you are using

```
typedef std::vector<Base*> Bases;  // or BaseVec or something
```

you would write

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, Bases>("racoon", Bases()));
```

that last part is creating an empty vector to pass as the second argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to call displayx(); using your second method?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. I'm just sad that I have to use C++98 so this is no longer possible. auto was introduced in C++11 was it not?

Comment: @Xirol I'll rewrite it for 98.

Comment: @Xirol See http://ideone.com/su89GU the "typedef"s near the top aleviate the pain of not having auto somewhat.

Comment: @Xirol and I added a second edit with the insert-based approach for C++98.

Comment: You are literally the best...Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, this is much simpler than you think:

```
Base * tanuki= new Derived;

std::map< string, vector<Base*>> myMap;

myMap["racoon"].push_back(tanuki);
```

`operator[]` gives you a reference to the value for the given key, value-initializing a new value, necessary. So you get your vector construct for free. Then you just `push_back`() the new element into the vector.